# firefox extension global variable

Tags: firefox, global-variables

How can I save values from an event function into a global variable in firefox extension or is there another better way?

Code:

```js
var bs = 
{
   onLoad: function() {...},
   onPress: function(e) {...},
   onMenuItemCommand: function(e) {...},
   onToolbarButtonCommand: function(e) {...},
};

window.addEventListener("load", function () { bs.onLoad(); }, false);
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {bs.onPress(e); }, false, true);
```

Tried to initialize before `var bs` but the variable is always reset.

Comment: It would help to have more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to make a form filler extension.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution,

If you declare the variable like this:

```
window['variablename'] = "";
```

you can access it in your functions.

Comment: That makes no difference.